# How I can get average time from dataGridView

Tags: c#

I have a dataGridView and i have Columns time 
i need get average the all time in this dataGridView
this my code to get average but it's don't work

```
 public void avghold()
    {

        double[] AVG_HLOD = new double[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
        AVG_HLOD = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                    where row.Cells["Avg_Hold"].FormattedValue.ToString()
                       != string.Empty
                    select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Avg_Hold"].FormattedValue)).ToArray();
        double Avghold = AVG_HLOD.Average();
       label17.Text = AVG_HLOD.Average().ToS
    }
```

[and this the image from the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh75c.png)

this error show when I click run 
[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpB3c.png)

Thanks for all,

Comment: Why is it not working?  What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: No error, but i don't see the average time in label or textbox

Comment: When stepping through this function - are you properly grabbing the values from the columns and converting them successfully?  I would start there and work my way up to updating the cells with averages.

Comment: I edit my post 
please show this image error,

Comment: In your code are you calling a .ToString() on the value you are passing back into the cell?  From a glance it seems like you are trying to insert a value not supported by the DataGridView.

Comment: Sory my pro, i cant understant of you..but this code in the post have any error ?!!
but if no have any error.can you know what's the problem ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
double avg = yourDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Average(x => int.Parse(x.Cells["Avg_Hold"].Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: no working, 
but no error when i run, but the average the time don't show in the label or textBox